# Arrival at Schipol airport at 6 am from close to Kronenburg tram stop?

Tags: public-transport, buses, taxis

We are staying very close to the Kronenburg tram stop (Amstelveen) and we need to be at the airport around 06:00 for an international flight. Would it be possible to catch a bus that early? And if so, where?

Comment: What day of the week? If I recall correctly, things start up at around 5 on weekdays, 6 on Saturdays, and 7 on Sundays.

Comment: a weekday. I thought things didn't start up until 0600 but I guess they start up earlier.

Comment: Amstelveen is in the city area for Amsterdam and there are night services in the area, besides, a lot of people working shifts in factories and at the airport change shift at 6 AM.

Answer (score 3):

You can get travel information in all of the Netherlands on [this 9292 site.](https://9292.nl/en)
At this time I can not get the English version to work but the [Dutch version](https://9292.nl/) did deliver results.

On a normal weekday this schedule will work.
Leave the Metro/tram stop at 5:29, metro 51, to metro/tram stop Oranjebaan, walk to bus stop Oranjebaan and take bus 300 to Schiphol. You should arrive just before 6 AM.

From this time of day onward there are regular metro's, trams and buses, overal travel times run from 22 to 35 minutes. (About 4 different connections will get you at Schiphol before 6:30.)
Earlier connections are by night bus and run about once per hour.

Weekends you are longer dependent on night buses. But those on Sunday morning seem to run every 15 minutes or so and take the same amount of time.

If there are several of you, look into a taxi, that might work out cheap enough. Pre-booked taxis are also available.

Comment: OK I will go this site. Dutch will work Thank you.